# recursively merging rows pandas dataframe based on the condition

Tags: python, pandas, recursion

community,

I have a sorted pandas dataframe that looks as following:

[image: sorted dataframe]

I want to merge rows that have overlapping values in **start** and **end** columns. Meaning that if the **end** value of initial row is bigger than **start** value of the sequential one or any othe sequential, they will be merged into one row. Examples are rows 3, 4 and 5. Output I would expect is:

[image]

To do so, I am trying to implement recursion function, that would loop over the dataframe until condition worsk and then return me a number that would be used to search location for the end row .

However, the functioin I am trying to implement, returns me empty dataframe. Could you help me please, where should I put attention, or what alternative can I build if recurtion is not a solution?

```
def row_merger(pd_df):

    counter = 0
    new_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=pd_df.columns)

    for i in range(len(pd_df) - 1):
        def recursion_inside(pd_df, counter = 0):
            counter = 0
            if pd_df.iloc[i + 1 + counter]["q.start"] <= pd_df.iloc[i]["q.end"]:
                counter = counter+1
                recursion_inside(pd_df, counter)
            else:
                return counter
        new_row = {"name": pd_df["name"][i], "q.start": pd_df.iloc[i]
                   ["q.start"], "q.end": pd_df.iloc[i+counter]["q.start"]}
        new_df.append(new_row, ignore_index=True)
    return new_df
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see the benefit of using recursion here, so I would just iterate over the rows instead, building up the rows for the output dataframe one by one, e.g. like this:

```py
def row_merger(df_in):

    if len(df_in) <= 1:
        return df_in

    rows_out = []
    current_row = df_in.iloc[0].values

    for next_row in df_in.iloc[1:].values:
        if next_row[1] > current_row[2]:
            rows_out.append(current_row)
            current_row = next_row
        else:
            current_row[2] = max(current_row[2], next_row[2])
    
    rows_out.append(current_row)
    return pd.DataFrame(rows_out, columns=df_in.columns)
```